# Historical Income Statements dataset

Tags: dataset, finance

I'm looking for some historical data for income statements on a quarterly basis. I'm aware that the sec website has them, but I could not find that data that I'm actually looking for. For example., here in this link, https://www.sec.gov/dera/data/financial-statement-data-sets I can download the zip files for every quarter, but if I look into the zip file, I could not make sense of the data and the files that it has.

All I'm looking for is a simple data that has the income statement just like how a company would report the income statement in their quarterly calls. Any help? Any ideas as to where else can I look for?